# How can I reference an appSetting in a different part of web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have my `appSettings` defined in a separate config file called `Appsettings.Dev.Config`, and I include that file inside my `web.config` file like so

```
<appSettings configSource="ConfigFiles\AppSettings.Dev.config"/>
```

Lets say one of the settings in the file is

```
<add key="MailerEmailAccount" value="myemail@myserver.com" />
```

Can I access the value of the setting `MailerEmailAccount` elsewhere inside web.config? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, the web configuration file cannot pull "settings" from itself; it's not dynamic at all.  The only sort of dynamic functionality is the ability to include other .config, but that's just a "suck all these settings in as if they were part of me" kind of thing.

Comment: I do that (pull in settings from another file) for appSettings and connectionStrings using the configSource attribute. That doesn't seem to be work for the mailSettings tag inside the system.net tag (or for the system.net tag itself). Is there a way to pull in settings besides appSettings and connectionStrings from other files?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are limitations to that; like you I use it mostly for appSettings and connectionStrings.  If you're using VS2010, you might also consider the Web.Config transformations: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/10/13/common-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Turns out that system.net and mailSettings tags cannot be sourced from a different file. However, the smtp tag (which is a child of mailSettings) can be. I am using web.config transformations but this particular issue could not be solved by just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible if you create a custom `ConfigurationSection` that pulls the value from `appSettings`.

Here's an article that explain how to create a custom configuration section:
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it's the only way I can think of to read a `web.config` setting from within the `web.config`.

**EDIT**

I haven't tested this, but maybe something like this would work?:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("localName", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
public string LocalName
{
    get
    {
        return this["localName"] as string;
    }
    set
    {                
        this["localName"] = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that haacked link and the code snippet. Not sure the code works for what I need right now but it is a good idea.