# Add "global variables" to app.config .NET

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config, global

I have a very large app.config files that has lots of bindings, and it's very difficult to handle them on multiple environments.

My question is: is there a way to define "global variables" in a app.config file. Then use those "variables" in the binding?

Below is a representation of what I need.

Is this possible/supported in app.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <key name="SomeEndPointAddress" value="http://localhost/service.svc">
  <key name="OtherEndPointAddress" value="http://localhost/OtherService.svc">


  <system.serviceModel>

       <endpoint 
          name="SomeEndPoint"
          address= SomeEndPointAddress
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

       ....

       <endpoint 
          name="OtherEndPoint"
          address= OtherEndPointAddress
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
    </client>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding/>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: maybe this is your question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680238/how-can-i-reference-an-appsetting-in-a-different-part-of-web-config

Comment: I think you should consider creating some basic ViewModel that will have those variables