# Retrieving an AppSettings value from a nested element in web.config

Tags: .net, web-config

How can I do if a want a nested element in web.config to have one of its values retrieved from AppSettings?

```
<element>
  <element2>
    <add virtualPath="[MyAppSettingsValue]" />
  </element2>
</element>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680238/how-can-i-reference-an-appsetting-in-a-different-part-of-web-config

Comment: And I thought I searched and couldn't find an answer, thanks!