# How to read App Setting key in Web config Connection string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It is possible to use app keys for all the connection string inputs and read those on connection string like bellow

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=$(Server);Initial Catalog=$(Catalog);User ID=$(User);Password=$(Password)" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />



<add key="$(Server)" value="xxxx" />
<add key="$(Catalog)" value="xxxx" />
<add key="$(User)" value="xxxx" />
<add key="$(Password)" value="xxxx" />
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i need to read those values as app keys as well

Comment: What you are trying to achieve seems unnecessary, if you are not going to use the `$(server)` and other settings individually elsewhere in the application as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680238/how-can-i-reference-an-appsetting-in-a-different-part-of-web-config). Actually you don't need to do this, that's why it's not possible. Because you can change the other parts of web.config same like AppSettings.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString =
String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};UserID={2};Password={3}",
 "server", "db", "ID", "Pass");
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Ertürk Öztürk already say - it's not possible.

If you searching for more or less clean way to do it i suggest you to use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DbConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) if you using not MSSQL data base.

In your code it will be like this with `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
//create connection string builder
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

//set all properties from your WebConfig
connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Catalog"];
connectionStringBuilder.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User"];
connectionStringBuilder.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

//not you can get rigth formatted connection string
var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
```