# How to use appsettings value in section property of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate

I want to use appsettings value in user defined section in web.cofig.

```
<coredistributedcache factory-class="NHibernate.Caches.CoreDistributedCache.Redis.RedisFactory,NHibernate.Caches.CoreDistributedCache.Redis">
    <properties>
      <property name="configuration">127.0.0.1:6379</property>
    </properties>
  </coredistributedcache>
```

I have already defined the configuration value in appsetting like this

```
<add key="RedisServer" value="127.0.0.1:6379" />
```

So basically I don't want to hard code property `configuration`  to `127.0.0.1:6379`, I want to set it like

```
<property name="configuration">{{RedisServer}}</property>
```

Is this even possible?

Or is there any other way to avoid duplication?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reference an appSetting in a different part of web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680238/how-can-i-reference-an-appsetting-in-a-different-part-of-web-config)

Comment: I don't think there is a way within the configuration itself. If you are using a third party tool like Octopus to perform deployment, you can perform configuration updates with parameters like this, in which case both locations would have the same placeholder to be replaced with the single value defined in Octopus. That probably doesn't really help for a local dev build though.

Answer (score 0):

The configs are not dynamic. However you can use [`WebConfigurationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager) to manupulate it.

This approach helps you, from [reference](https://forums.asp.net/t/2132952.aspx?update+web+config+custom+values+in+asp+net) :

```
var configFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ClientSettingsSection section = (ClientSettingsSection)configFile.SectionGroups["applicationSettings"].Sections[0];
var value = section.Settings;
SettingElement settingElement = new SettingElement();
SettingValueElement settingValueElement = new SettingValueElement();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));
XmlNodeList nodeList;
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("applicationSettings");
var valuenode = nodeList[0].SelectNodes("coredistributedcache/properties/property")[0];
var oldValue = valuenode.InnerText;
valuenode.InnerText = "New Value1";
settingValueElement.ValueXml = valuenode;
settingElement.Value = settingValueElement;
value.Clear();
value.Add(settingElement);
configFile.Save();
```

Comment: Setting aside the fact that this is way more complex than just putting an IP address in the config twice, would it really work? I would expect the Nhibernate config to be read upon creation of the app domain which means changes afterwards will not affect the Nhibernate instance already generated. Do you know if this is the case or not?

Comment: You are definitely right, agree with you. My answer adds more complexity, we can say that it is more like workaround. But it may helps..